# How do I make my restaurant site buttons display the overlays correctly?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, jsx

I'm having trouble getting the buttons on my restaurant website built in React.js to display overlay pages correctly. They are set up in a component of their own (MenuButtons.jsx) and sit at the bottom of a shorter menu section on the front page (see image below). I want them to launch separate overlay pages for the remaining sections of the menu (e.g wine list, lunch menu etc) as the complete menu is too long to include all of it on the front page. The second image below shows how the wine list overlay should look.

Here's the code, below:

```
   import React, { useState } from "react";
   import WinesOverlay from 
   "../../components/WinesOverlay/WinesOverlay";

const MenuButtons = () => {
  const [overlay, setOverlay] = useState(null);
  const renderOverlay = (value) => {
    if (!value) {
      return;
    } else if (value === "wines") {
      return (
        <div className="app__specialMenu-smallscreen">
          <WinesOverlay />
        </div>
      );
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="app__specialMenu-buttons">
      <button
        onClick={(renderOverlay) => setOverlay("wines")}
        type="button"
        className="custom__button"
      >
        WINES
      </button>

      <button type="button" className="custom__button">
        SPIRITS & LIQUEURS
      </button>

      <button type="button" className="custom__button">
        LUNCH MENU
      </button>

      <button type="button" className="custom__button">
        DINNER MENU
      </button>

      <button type="button" className="custom__button">
        SOFT DRINKS
      </button>

      <button type="button" className="custom__button">
        BEVERAGES
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MenuButtons;
```

[Restaurant site front page menu section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzNUE.png)

[Restaurant site wine list overlay page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWZz9.png)

I tried re-using some code from the navigation bar section (which launches a single overlay page from a hamburger menu at the top of the front page) to import the wine list as a component (see first screenshot below). That worked for the first button (wines) but when I attempted to replicate the code for the second button (spirits & liqueurs), the overlays for both the wines and spirits/liqueurs buttons displayed the content from the spirits & liqueurs component.

[Menu buttons code - wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvABB.png)

I've been advised to rewrite the MenuButtons.jsx code thus (see second screenshot below):
1: Declaring the state at the top of the component (line 5): const [overlay, setOverlay] = useState(null);
2: Creating a component that receives the string "wines" as a prop based on the string that's set in state and that renders the WinesOverlay component (lines 6-14).
3: Adding the label "wines" to the onClick handler (line 21).

Not sure if I've written the code in MenuButtons.jsx correctly or in the right order. But the wines button doesn't do anything, so I don't know if the rewritten code is any closer to what it needs to be.

If I can just get the first button working properly the rest should be fairly straightforward. Any advice much appreciated.

[Menu buttons code - current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOQGv.png)

Comment: Please add a code snippet or code sandbox instead of screenshots of code. It would be easier for someone to help that way.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please checkout the [tour], [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and [ask]. Additionally, take a look at [mre]. In the current state, there is not enough context/code to help you with you question.

Comment: Thanks Harshit T, have added code from MenuButtons.jsx now.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not passing the 'value' to the renderOverlay while using it with onClick and also you have declared the onClick for Wines button incorrectly.
As you have used an inline arrow function which just updates your overlay value to "wines" and does not call the renderOverlay anywhere.
{(rendeOverlay) =>... this is passing the function as the argument not calling it.
Correct it like this.

```
<button
   onClick={() => {
      renderOverlay("wines");
   } />
```

Kindly do let me know for any queries.

Comment: Thanks Ashutosh, will give that a try.

Comment: Hi Ashutosh, I notice you've got the button in a self-closing tag above. But mne is like this:
`<button onClick={() => renderOverlay("wines")}`
`type="button"`
`className="custom__button">`
`WINES`
`</button>`

Also, I'm now getting the error message below: 
`Line 5:  'overlay' is assigned a value but never used     no-unused-vars`
`Line 5:  'setOverlay' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars`

I currently have two return statements as well. Don't think that's right. Wines button still not working

Comment: Also, in your code snippet below, there are two opening curly braces but only one closing one:

`<button
   onClick={() => {
      renderOverlay("wines");
   } />`

Comment: My apologies for the wrong braces implementation, and as far as concerned with the value assigned but not used, you can remove them if not in use or you can do one more thing like this 
`<button onClick={() =>`
`{ setOverlay("wines");  renderOverlay("wines" ) }`
`} />`
So that you can use it as you want.

Comment: I think we should connect - https://www.linkedin.com/in/ashutosh0299/